# Loading High Frequency Data in R

Tags: r

Trying to load 1m data of IWM, the russell 2000 etf. The data looks like this.

```
        Date     Time   Open   High    Low  Close Volume
1 03/18/2014 08:00:00 118.39 118.43 118.39 118.43    980
2 03/18/2014 08:01:00 118.45 118.45 118.45 118.45    400
3 03/18/2014 08:02:00 118.47 118.47 118.46 118.47   1200
4 03/18/2014 08:03:00 118.43 118.43 118.43 118.43    500
5 03/18/2014 08:04:00 118.39 118.39 118.39 118.39   1400
6 03/18/2014 08:05:00 118.38 118.38 118.38 118.38   1700
```

How do I tell R to recognize that the data is of high frequency nature after I have loaded it in, so I can plot/etc? I am trying to use the zoo package but I am not sure how to tell it that `data$Date` is the date and `data$Time` is the time stamp for a given date.

Comment: try `vignette("zoo-read")`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give `zoo` a column in the data frame it can work on and ensure it treats it as `POSIXct` vs the standard `Date` type:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = c("03/18/2014", "03/18/2014", "03/18/2014", 
                                "03/18/2014", "03/18/2014", "03/18/2014"), 
                       Time = c("08:00:00", "08:01:00", "08:02:00", "08:03:00", 
                                "08:04:00", "08:05:00"), 
                       Open = c(118.39, 118.45, 118.47, 118.43, 118.39, 118.38), 
                       High = c(118.43, 118.45, 118.47, 118.43, 118.39, 118.38), 
                       Low = c(118.39, 118.45, 118.46, 118.43, 118.39, 118.38), 
                       Close = c(118.43, 118.45, 118.47, 118.43, 118.39, 118.38), 
                       Volume = c(980L, 400L, 1200L, 500L, 1400L, 1700L)), \
                       .Names = c("Date", "Time", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"), 
                       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(zoo)

data$ts <- as.POSIXct(strptime(sprintf("%s %s", data$Date, data$Time), 
                               "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))

# don't need the Date/Time columns anymore

data.zoo <- read.zoo(data[,3:8], index.column=c(6), FUN=as.POSIXct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below we create a test data file called testdata.dat and then read it in using `read.zoo`.  note that there is extensive help on read.zoo (`?read.zoo`) and an entire vignette of `read.zoo` examples http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-read.pdf

```
# create test data
Lines <- "Date     Time   Open   High    Low  Close Volume
1 03/18/2014 08:00:00 118.39 118.43 118.39 118.43    980
2 03/18/2014 08:01:00 118.45 118.45 118.45 118.45    400
3 03/18/2014 08:02:00 118.47 118.47 118.46 118.47   1200
4 03/18/2014 08:03:00 118.43 118.43 118.43 118.43    500
5 03/18/2014 08:04:00 118.39 118.39 118.39 118.39   1400
6 03/18/2014 08:05:00 118.38 118.38 118.38 118.38   1700"
cat(Lines, file = "testdata.dat")

# read it in
library(zoo)
fmt <- "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
z <- read.zoo("testdata.dat", index = 1:2, tz = "", format = fmt)
```

`index=1:2` indicates that the first two columns hold the time index and `tz=""` indicates that POSIXct class is is wanted for the index using the local time zone.  `format=fmt` specifies the format of the index.  Since there is one more data column than there are fields on the first line it will assume the first line is a header line and the first column on lines after the first are rownames. If there were no rownames then `header=TRUE` would be needed.

Modify the `read.zoo` line appropriately if your data is not in precisely in the form shown.

If you already have the data in a data frame then use the `read.zoo` command just shown but replace the file name with the data.frame:

```
DF <- read.table("testdata.dat")
z <- read.zoo(DF, index = 1:2, tz = "", format = fmt)
```